# Does apple maps and MapKit use the same API?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

When I do a search in the Apple maps and one in my app using MapKit I get two different results for "New York".

Do they both use the same api?

If I do a search for "New York" in apple maps it will place the pointer in the center of NY city. But if I do a search for "New York" with MapKit using `MKLocalSearchRequest` and `naturalLanguageQuery` it will place the pointer a bit off, not even in Manhattan.

code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.mapView.delegate = self


        localSearchRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
        localSearchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "New York"
        localSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: localSearchRequest)
        localSearch.startWithCompletionHandler { (localSearchResponse, error) -> Void in



            if localSearchResponse == nil || self.mapView == nil{
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Not found", message: "Try again", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
                return
            } else {

                let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.latitude, longitude:     localSearchResponse.boundingRegion.center.longitude)


                let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
                let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)
                self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)


                self.pointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                self.pointAnnotation.coordinate = location
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(self.pointAnnotation)
            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: You're clearly asking the wrong question.  You need to show the code you're using to produce the result that is not accurate enough for you and then probably ask about how you can make it more accurate.

Comment: @nhgrif update my question with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they don't use the same api for displaying so I'd also assume they don't use the public API for searching.

Especially given the fact that the app came earlier than the API

## BUT thats likely besides the point

You don't set the region property: "A map region that provides a hint as to where to search." (at least it isn't the same as in apple maps it seems)

**for me it returns only ONE result as well [using mapkit]**